# Modelsim change displayed value radix of variables in debug mode

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

can I change the radix of the displayed value when I'm running with the curser over a variable?[image]

So if if hover with my mouse over a variable in debug mode(because a break point was reached) a binary radix is for me not useful. Is there a way to change this radix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the Modelsim graphic interface open you might change the radix following the steps bellow:

1. Select *Simulate* > *Runtime options...*
2. In *Default Radix* box,select your desired radix

Hope that helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set it up permanently, open **modelsim.ini** (sometimes, you may have to change the permission of this file- default is read-only) in your modelsim installation folder, navigate to

> DefaultRadix = symbolic

and change it to

> DefaultRadix = hex
>
> DefaultRadixFlags = showbase

After that restart modelsim. This will set your default radix in the wave window to hexadecimal.